# Execute functionality before each URL and then redirect in Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony

I want to check for some user meta values before each URL is processed. During that process I want to skip some specials URL such as login, login and of course need to get the current user as well.

NOTE: I want to check for other functionalities and redirect before it passes onto controller. Don't want to change the response but request. Hope this is the correct event.

I am currently hooking in `kernel.request` event and doing something like this

Create subscriber

```
profile_check_subscriber:
        class: BBT\MainBundle\EventListener\ProfileCheckSubscriber
        arguments: ['@user_manager', '@router.default']
        tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

And then in ProfileCheckSubscriber class

```
class ProfileCheckSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

/**
 * @var UserManager
 */
private $userManager;
/**
 * @var Router
 */
private $router;

public function __construct(UserManager $userManager, Router $router)
{
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
    $this->router = $router;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'kernel.request' => 'onKernelRequest'
    );
}

public function onKernelRequest( GetResponseEvent $event)
{

    $request_uri = $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

    $logout_url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_security_logout');

    //don't proceed on these urls
    $check_url_array = array(
        $logout_url,
        $this->router->generate('user_welcome'),
        $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed'),
        $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_register'),
        $this->router->generate('fos_user_security_check'),
        $this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login')
    );

    if( $event->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'GET' )
        return;

    if( $event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() )
        return;

    if( in_array( $request_uri, $check_url_array ) )
        return;

    if( false !== strpos( $request_uri, 'f/f_edit' ) )
        return;

    if( false !== strpos( $request_uri, 'register' ) )
        return;

    if( 'anon.' == $this->userManager->current_user || false == $this->userManager->current_user )
        return;

    //good to process

    $forced_profile_page_url = $this->router->generate('user_forced_pages', array('page_type' => 'profile_picture'));
    $profile_fields_url = $this->router->generate('user_profile_edit');

    $profile_image_check = $this->userManager->getSingleMeta('force_profile_image_set');

    $profile_fields_check = $this->userManager->getSingleMeta('force_profile_fields_set');

    if( true == $profile_image_check  && $request_uri != $forced_profile_page_url ){
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse( $forced_profile_page_url ));
    } elseif( true == $profile_fields_check && $request_uri != $profile_fields_url && $request_uri !== $forced_profile_page_url ) {
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse( $profile_fields_url ));
    }

}

}
```

Here `userManager` is my customer in which `current_user` is retrieved by security token.

This code works perfectly if I use `kernel.response` and using `FilterResponseEvent` instead of `GetResponseEvent` but fails to run on `kernel.request` because it cannot find the current user logged in.
I am not sure how `kernel.request` is messing up the session.

**UPDATE:** 
Sorry guys, back to the drawing board. Setting the priority didn't get the user. So still not able to get the user. Tried priority 0 and 50. No luck!

Comment: It is `$this->userManager->current_user` the same as `$this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();` where `$securityContext` is the `security.context` service?

Comment: @absalon.valdes `getToken` of `security.context` has been deprecated. I am getting the user from token_storage as mentioned here http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: There are probably some other listeners that construct the user for the `token_storage` that execute later than your listener. lower the priority for your listener and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @user2268997 setting priority works but I didn't solve my problem. I am updating the question description.

Comment: @KaranKhanna my bad. wrong version. maybe setting a priority **higher**  than 0.

Comment: @absalon.valdes settings any priority solves the error but I want to redirect before it reached the controller. Here everything in respective controller is getting run and then it redirects.

Comment: Sorry guys setting the priority didn't solve the problem. Still not able to get the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the event listened to `kernel.controller`?

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    /* all your logic */
    $redirectUrl = /** something **/
    $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    });
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-controller-event

Comment: This looks promising. I will test a bit more and update you.

Comment: Btw `$this->tokenStorage`is a instance of `@security.token_storage` service.

Comment: Thanks that works :)..why is `kernel.request` not working?

Comment: Because the session is created **only** after the request object is created in kernel.request event. Look the SessionListener http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request